# Dart Callbacks :How to pass ' void Function(MyType) ' argument to ' void Function(dynamic) ' parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I want to build a custom AppBar `EntityAdderAppBar` that is responsible for adding different business entities to a database(Firestore). The class should accept the `addEntity` method as an argument, then execute this method when a button pressed.
The following is a simplified version of my classes:

#### EntityAdderAppBar

```
typedef AdderCallback=void Function(dynamic entity);
class EntityAdderAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  const EntityAdderAppBar({
    required this.adder,
    required this.entity,
  });
  final AdderCallback adder;
  final dynamic entity;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ......
       onPressed: () async {
         adder(entity);
       .......
}
```

And here is where I want to use `EntityAdderAppBar`

#### EntityItemScreen

```
class SourceItemScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntityItemScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: EntityAdderAppBar(
        entity: entityObject,
        adder: EntityDataRepository().addEntity,
      ),
```

Passing the addEntity method to the adder parameter produces the following error

`The argument type 'void Function(Entity)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.`
What am I missing, or what's wrong with my design?

Comment: Can you include more about `EntityDataRepository().addEntity,`

Comment: an `AdderCallback` must be a function with a dynamic parameter. addEntity only accepts `Entity`. I don't know if it's the best way to solve it but you could try to refactor `addEntity` to work with a dynamic parameter

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it's a void function that takes Entity as an argument, and contains logic to add Entity to the database. Entity is just an abstraction of business entities in my project. There is no concrete class called Entity.

Comment: @Ivo I thought of this solution, but this will require me to refactor all the business entities model classes in the project. I think there is a better design.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh here is a concrete implementation of addEntity. `   @override
  void addSource(sourcedto.Source source) async {
    await _db.collection("sources").add(source.toFirestore());
  }
`